# Alamofire String is not identical to AnyObject error

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, alamofire

I use Alamofire in Swift 2. So, I have parameters:

```
let parameters = [
        "fullname": fullName.text,
        "username": username.text,
        "email": email.text,
        "password": password.text,
        "country": country
    ]
```

and send request via:

```
Alamofire.request(Method.POST, "http://myapi.mysite.com/users", parameters: parameters)
            .response { request, response, data, error in
```

but it returns me the next error, that `parameters`

```
'String?' is not identical to 'AnyObject'
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: What type is `country`? You might have to cast it to a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we look into Alamofire closely, we'll find that the method request looks like this:

```
public func request(
    method: Method,
    _ URLString: URLStringConvertible,
    parameters: [String: AnyObject]? = nil,
    encoding: ParameterEncoding = .URL,
    headers: [String: String]? = nil)
    -> Request
```

So we can see, that `parameters` is of type `[String : AnyObject]?`, which is optional itself, but only the array as a whole. The parameters inside cannot be optional. Your parameters you're adding to the dictionary are optional, so it's necessary to unwrap them. It is fairly common to use the safety structures in Swift, so forcing `!` just to surpass the compiler is not the smartest option. Use if-let for handling it:

```
if let fullname = fn.text, un = username.text, em = email.text, pwd = password.text {
    let parameters = [
        //...
    ]
} else {
    // handle the situation - inform the user they forgot some fields
}
```

As for your `Cannot call value of non-function type 'NSHTTPURLResponse?'` problem:

The issue is with [Alamofire 2.0 migration](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%202.0%20Migration%20Guide.md) where the response serialization has rapidly changed, so for your case use it like this:

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, "https://myapi.mysite.com/users", parameters: parameters) 
    .responseJSON { _, _, result in 
        print(result) 
        // mumbo jumbo
}
```

Comment: Is it for iOS 9? You **have** to use http**s** in iOS 9, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: where must I use https?

Comment: Well in the query - in your previous comment you had something like `http://api.a4.co/...` (can't remember exact address) - in iOS 9 you have to use https.

Comment: No, it's not a solution of `Cannot call value of non-function type 'NSHTTPURLResponse?'`

Comment: Hmmm...could you post some more code? Like the whole method where you are calling the POST?

Comment: Could you add the whole function where this request is implemented?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89658/discussion-between-orkhan-and-michal).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to unpack the text fields! This has happened to me a LOT since converting to Swift 2. Might be worth a try

```
let parameters = [
        "fullname": fullName.text!,
        "username": username.text!,
        "email": email.text!,
        "password": password.text!,
        "country": country
    ]
```

Comment: Yes, it worksm but now it prints `Cannot call value of non-function type 'NSHTTPURLResponse?'`

Answer (score 0):

You value in your dictionary is an Optional type. You should be able to get rid of the error if you unwrap it with a bang `!`

Comment: Yes, it worksm but now it prints Cannot call value of non-function type 'NSHTTPURLResponse?'